# How do I scrape URLs from a JavaScript 'onclick window.open' event?

Tags: javascript, ruby, screen-scraping, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to scrape URLs from a page that uses JavaScript. Instead of having links on the page, they created `onClick` events for a number of table rows, whereby, when you click the row, it takes you to the link.

I tried scraping the URLs using Mechanize:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

page.links_with(:href => /^http?/).each do |link|
  puts link.href
end
```

But, looking for links via a HREF reference doesn't work here, because they're on the page as part of the `onClick` event:

```
<tr onclick="window.open('/someurl');">
```

Is there a good way to use Mechanize, or some other gem, to parse the code on the page and extract the URLs embedded in the `onClick` event?

If there's no good out-of-the-box solution, what might be the best regex to do that? I'm a little new to regex, so not quite able to pull together something on my own yet.

Comment: Are all of the links in the same format?

Comment: Also perhaps add the URL to the page you are scraping if possible, so people can take a look at the source. Helps you get answers faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a parser. Regex and HTML/XML don't mix well, because regex are not designed to handle the irregularities HTML and XML documents contain. Very simple tasks might work with a pattern, but you'll quickly find they are fragile and easily broken when the HTML changes.

Mechanize for Ruby, uses [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) internally, which is an excellent way to get at those parameters. You can access Mechanize's internal Nokogiri document and, from it, find the `<tr>` tags:

```
require 'mechanize'

page = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://somesite.foo.com')

page.search('tr[onclick]').map{ |n| n['onclick'][/\(['"]([^)]+)['"]\)/, 1] }
```

If I use Nokogiri directly to parse this fragment:

```
<tr onclick="window.open('/someurl');">
```

I can do this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(%[<tr onclick="window.open('/someurl');">])
page.search('tr[onclick]').map{ |n| n['onclick'][/\(['"]([^)]+)['"]\)/, 1] }
=> ["/someurl"]
```

Notice that I'm searching using a CSS accessor `'tr[onclick]'`, which makes it pretty easy to find a particular node. If you know JavaScript, CSS or jQuery you'll find it pretty easy to pick up Nokogiri using its built-in support for CSS.

Also,

```
n['onclick'][/\(['"]([^)]+)['"]\)/, 1]
```

could be written alternately as:

```
n['onclick'][/\(([^)]+)\)/, 1][1..-2]
```

Comment: That's great - the search and mapping worked perfectly. Should I interpret the regex as follows: 1) Find an open bracket 2) find a single or double quote 3) find all characters that aren't close bracket 4) find a closing quote 5) find a closing bracket...? What does the '1' argument passed in represent? Thanks!

Comment: That's how to read the regex. What `1` means is left for you to figure out. See the docs for `String.[]`.